# Apache Nifi: how to set the content of a flow file as an attribute

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

I am trying to fetch some data via an api and want to set the result of the api as an attribute of the flow file. I am able to fetch the data via the api but cannot seem to set it as a an attribute.
[image: the flow]

[image: I tried setting it this way, but it did not work.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of the `EvaluateJsonPath` processor to get the desired data from the flowfile into the Attribute.

The below sample flow invokes an API and gets data

[image: Sample Flow]

The content of the response that is received

[image: Flowfile Content]

Properties set in the `EvaluateJsonPath` to pull the length value as an Attribute

[image: EvaluateJsonPath]

The output of the processor sets the Attribute Key with its corresponding value

[image: Attribute Value]

To set the API response as a whole into the Attribute set the `KEY` with the value as `$` and `Return Type` as `JSON`

[image: EvaluateJsonPath Property]

[image: API Response]

Comment: so whats the nifi expresssion to fetch the payload, I can see you have used $.length to fetch the length similarly how can I fetch the contents of api response

Comment: I guess you haven't gone through the whole answer then :)